# C - Is this truncate of char array safe?

Tags: c

I'm using C.  For this example, assume the char buf will always end in ", " (which I have no control over) and we will always want to truncate the last two characters (e.g. remove the ", ").  Also assume that it won't exceed 128 characters.  Is the below code safe (with those assumptions)?

```
char buf[128];
sprintf(buf, "Item One, Item Two, Item Three, Item Four, ");

int len = strlen(buf);
if (len > 2)
{
    // We know it's greater than 2, lop off the last two characters
    buf[len - 2] = '\0';
}
```

If this isn't safe what is the best way to truncate the last few characters of a null terminated char array?

Comment: It's a pretty common technique. Multi-byte character sets might make it unsafe, but then you wouldn't be using `strlen()`.

Comment: Good point.  In this scenario it wouldn't be using Unicode.

Comment: Suggest `size_t len` rather than `int len`.  That is the type returned by `strlen()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes** it is safe, since because of the if statement, you are not in danger of accessing memory you do not own. However, I would change `len` to be of type `size_t`, which is the return type of [strlen()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/).

---

Moreover, I would change the if statement to `if (len >= 2)`, in order to take care of the case that only the characters you want to cut off are appearing in the `buf`. That way, the truncated string will be an empty string(since the string terminator will be placed in the position 0).